# mail.app does not reliably signal attachments in paper clip column of message viewer

Tags: mail.app

10.12.6 Sierra, Mail.app  v10.3 (3273)

Q: *Why didn't you respond to the issue in the attachment I sent you yesterday?*

--looks at incoming item in message view--

A: *Because my mail client didn't signal that there was an attachment with that message.*

--opens full view for that item, spots paper-clip icon to the right of sender name--

A:  *Ahh, yes, you did send me an attachment yesterday.  I'll open it now...*

--successfully opens attachment--

---

Control-click in the column headers of mail.app's message viewer and enable "Attachments".  This adds a column labeled with a paperclip icon.  The viewer row for an incoming email that includes an attachment places a paperclip in that icon, and --if the column is adjusted wide enough-- you also see text like "1 item", "2 items..." indicating the number of attachments.  (Right?)

This doesn't seem to be working -- not reliably, anyway.

(I think I've seen this for many years, through many versions. But I've tried to ignore it, hoping it would get fixed eventually.)

Fix for new messages?

Retroactive fix?

TIA

Comment: I have 3 places that show if there is an attachment. 1- in the list view (coulomb), 2- in the email header, 3- and under the email header. Do you have those ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

1- I call this "message view".  my issue: mail.app does not reliably indicate attachments in this view.

2- email header --  When viewing a message, if there's  an attachment, a paperclip icon displayed  to the right of the Sender's name, the top-most item.  

3-  Under the email header --   When viewing a  message, below the header is a faint grey line, right?   At the center point of this ine is small  horizontal menu, visible on mouse-over. Yes, the right-most item is a paperclip if there is an attachment, with an attachment count next to it.